# How to extract BPM of an MP3 file in TarsosDSP (Android)

Tags: java, android, tarsosdsp

I've been developing a player which can extract the audio tags and other metadata. I'm using mp3agic for ID3 tag management, but I want to implement a method in which the MP3 file is analyzed to find the BPM (Beats Per Minute) of the said MP3 file. I stumbled upon TarsosDSP package for the processing. The problem is, I really don't know method or class to use from the package to do such a thing. If anyone could help me write a method for this, it would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!